# Jenkins plugin for Selenium 3

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I am automating test cases for my application using Selenium 3. The next step is to put these test into Jenkins. I looked into Jenkins plugins and all I could find relevant was [Selenium Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin) - This plugin turns your Jenkins cluster into a Selenium2 Grid cluster.

Is this the correct plugin to install?

Any suggestions for running Selenium 3 tests on Jenkins.

Comment: What about [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Seleniumhq+Plugin), which seems to let you specify an arbitrary selenium executable -so you could just download the `jar` file for selenium3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a jenkins server up and running? Just have it point at your code (local or repo) and configure the build goals.

Comment: yes, the jenkins server is up and running, but doesn't running Selenium test require configuring plugins?? or is it just the goals that are required?

Answer (score 0):

You do not require selenium to run your code in Jenkins, you can run it by directly pointing your local code location in Jenkins, i.e. if you're using Maven project for Selenium the you need to point pom.xml file only in Jenkins.